# VB.NET Divisions problems

Tags: vb.net

First of all, I would like you to know that I am really rookie on this platform and in vb.net language. I have a question, I wanted to ask you, since I couldn't make any progress in about 3 hours. I think it's very simple for someone who knows.

If the number entered from the textbox is odd, multiply by 3 and add 1, if it is double, this process will be divided by 2, and this process should continue until the number is "1". I try to write the code of the program that finds how many steps this process takes (number of processes), the maximum value of the number during the process and the number that the number always reaches 1 in pairs with VB.NET.

Is there anyone who can help? I want you to know that I was really struggling, trying to learn, but not enough

As I said, I scribbled something, but I am not even on the right track.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM3mM.png)

```
enter code here
 Dim number1 As Double
Dim tislem As Double
Dim result As Double
Dim çislem As Double
Dim i As Double

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    number1 = TextBox1.Text
    çislem = number1 / 2
    tislem = number1 * 3 + 1
    If number1 Mod (2) = 1 Then
        result = tislem
        MessageBox.Show("sayı tektir" + result.ToString())
        For i = 1 To result = 0
            result = number1 / 2
        Next i
        MessageBox.Show("sayı tektir" + result.ToString())


    Else MessageBox.Show("sayı çifttir")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Please [read How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), knowing how to ask is the key to get an answer around here. Also, post what you've tried, even if it doesn't work as you would like, so we have something to work with AndAlso see that you're not trying to trick us into doing your homework in your place.

Comment: This is very basic and you'll easily get help as long as you play by our rules. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question. I shared the codes.

Comment: For anyone interested, this is related to the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) - does the Collatz sequence eventually reach 1 for all positive integer initial values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood exactly what you're trying to do (neither of us have english as a first language it seems). I'm still trying, but make sure that you understand what I'm doing or I may lead you off target.

It seems to me that the worst problem here is using a `For` loop instead of a `While` loop. You could also do without some of these variables. Here's some code to give you a hand:

```
' I suggest that you add these two lines at the very top of your code
' It'll force you to type your variables, which is a great way to avoid all kind of mistakes
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Here I'm protecting you against errors caused if the user enters a non-numeric
    ' Your teached probably didn't ask for this but it's good to know nonetheless
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        ' Converting text to double (it was done implicitely in your code, but it's better to understand what's happening to better control it)
        Dim myNumber As Double = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) ' CDbl as in 'Convert DouBLe'
        Dim maxNumber as Double = myNumber

        ' If the number is odd, we multiply by 3 and add 1
        If myNumber Mod 2 = 1 Then
            myNumber = (myNumber * 3) + 1
            If myNumber > maxNumber Then maxNumber = myNumber
        End If

        ' Let's count how many divisions before there's only 1 left
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While (myNumber > 1)
            myNumber = myNumber / 2
            i += 1
        End While

        MessageBox.Show("It took " & i.ToString & " divisions until my number was reduced to 1. The max number was " & maxNumber.ToString & ".")
    Else
        ' This will appear if you try to use non-numeric, like letters
        MessageBox.Show("Use only numbers.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest and for your answer. The code you shared is working. So how do we find the last split even number ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you rephrase so I get the idea?

Comment: and where can I like your answer I am looking for it :) I think I could

Comment: `IsNumeric`? How about `Double.TryParse`? You won't need the `NullOfWhiteSpace`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
Dim number1 As Double
Dim maxNumber As Double = 0
Dim steps as Double = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    number1 = TextBox1.Text
    MessageBox.Show($"Sayı {If( (number1 Mod 2) = 1, "tektir", "çifttir") }")
    While number1 > 1
        number1 = If((number1 Mod 2) = 1, number1 * 3 + 1, number1 * 2)
        maxNumber = Math.Max(number1, maxNumber)
        steps += 1 
    End While
    MessageBox.Show($"Steps: {steps}{Environment.NewLine}Max number reached: {maxNumber}")
End Sub
```

You should write a proper loop in order to repeat this process until you reach 1. Moreover, it is better for you that if you get used to use ***&*** symbol instead of ***+*** symbol to concat strings.